# SVN revision equals number of commits?

Tags: svn

If I go to the root of a SVN repository and look at the head revision number:

[image]

Does that equal the total number of commits made to the whole repository (including any commits made on branches, trunk etc.)?

Comment: What you look at seems to be BASE of a working copy, not HEAD. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html I.e. you are looking at working copy's log. The repository's  HEAD may be higher than 2867.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

As [SVN book says](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html):

> Each time the repository accepts a commit, this creates a new state of
>   the filesystem tree, called a revision. Each revision is assigned a
>   unique natural number, one greater than the number assigned to the
>   previous revision. The initial revision of a freshly created
>   repository is numbered 0 and consists of nothing but an empty root
>   directory.